# Why ClientID didn't change in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

Here is the strange ClientID behavior, you can reproduce it by below steps:

1. Create a web project, using .net 3.5
2. Add a new WebUserControl
3. Add a text box in the control `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>`
4. In the Default page, add a PlaceHolder, `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTest"></asp:PlaceHolder>`
5. In code behind, add:

   ```
   protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   {
       var ctl = (WebUserControl1)LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx");
       var id = ctl.Txt1.ClientID;
       phTest.Controls.Add(ctl);
       id += " - " + ctl.Txt1.ClientID;
       ctl.Txt1.Text = id;
       base.OnPreRender(e);
   }
   ```
6. Broswer the page and you'll see `txt1 - txt1`
7. If you change framework to .Net4, and use `clientIDMode="AutoID"`, the result will be `txt1 - ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_txt1`

Normally the clientID should be added prefix if it add to another container, but why here the clientID didn't change?

I just want to know is this by design or just a bug. Thanks.